# jump to specific line in matlab

Tags: matlab, numbers, export, line

I have a large txt file size:1gb and I have starting and ending line numbers of the parts in a text file I need, in vectors.

I have a specific code I can run on individual parts, how can I jump to the specific line number and end the routine at the ending line number (I prefer not to use loops as the size of file is huge and it takes a lot of time moreover I need a technique where we don't always count on line 1 to get to the specific line I'd also want to know how to export these parts to some other txt file, hopefully I might do processing faster in the exported file)

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: Check with _fseek_.

Comment: @fujy what part of code do you need?

Comment: @maz take a look on the `dlmread` examples on this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-numeric-data-from-a-text-file.html#br305ez)